# PHP's Solr plugin returning different spellcheck data

Tags: php, solr

When I do a query (for example 'gluue') utilizing PHP's Solr plugin I get different spellcheck collation results then when using Solr's url based system.

http://xxx:8080/solr/example/browse?q=gluue%0A&wt=xml&spellcheck=true

returns :

```
<lst name="spellcheck"><lst name="suggestions"><lst name="gluue"><int name="numFound">10</int><int name="startOffset">0</int><int name="endOffset">5</int><arr name="suggestion"><str>glue</str><str>gauge</str><str>glide</str><str>glove</str><str>glued</str><str>globe</str><str>glaze</str><str>gluten</str><str>gauze</str><str>glues</str></arr></lst><lst name="collation"><str name="collationQuery">glue
</str><int name="hits">74</int><lst name="misspellingsAndCorrections"><str name="gluue">glue</str></lst></lst><lst name="collation"><str name="collationQuery">gauge
</str><int name="hits">6</int><lst name="misspellingsAndCorrections"><str name="gluue">gauge</str></lst></lst><lst name="collation"><str name="collationQuery">glide
</str><int name="hits">7</int><lst name="misspellingsAndCorrections"><str name="gluue">glide</str></lst></lst></lst></lst>
```

PHP plugin (replicating the query above exactly confirming within solrs log file)

```
[spellcheck] => SolrObject Object
    (
        [suggestions] => SolrObject Object
            (
                [gluue] => SolrObject Object
                    (
                        [numFound] => 10
                        [startOffset] => 0
                        [endOffset] => 5
                        [suggestion] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => glue
                                [1] => gauge
                                [2] => glide
                                [3] => glove
                                [4] => glued
                                [5] => globe
                                [6] => glaze
                                [7] => gluten
                                [8] => gauze
                                [9] => glues
                            )

                    )

                [collation] => SolrObject Object
                    (
                        [collationQuery] => glide
                        [hits] => 7
                        [misspellingsAndCorrections] => SolrObject Object
                            (
                                [gluue] => glide
                            )

                    )

            )

    )
```

Note the 3 collationQuery values in the first response and only one in the PHP plugin.

The boss likes the first response ("glue") better so I'm going to have to bypass the plugin just for the spellcheck feature (and add an additional query to my system) because of this.  Any ideas?  I would really like to avoid this.